# enabling and disabling two text box at the same time based on selection option choice

Tags: javascript

I have four category namely men, women, youth and both(men and women) when i choose men category at the select option  the text box to enter number of women is disabled and when i choose women category the text box to enter number of men is disabled, what i ask for help is how to make the two text box be active at the same time when i choose youth or both category. Below is my code.

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="category" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Group Category</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
         <select class="form-control" name="category"  id="category" onChange="JoinedOrNot()">
      <option value="">Select Category</option>
      <option value="Men">Men</option>
      <option value="Women">Women</option>
      <option value="Youth">Youth</option>
      <option value="Both">Both</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Number Of Men</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type='text' size='5' name="man" id="input1" value="" class='input' disabled></input>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Number Of Women</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type='text' size='5' name="woman" id="input2" value="" class='input' disabled></input>
    </div>
    </div>
```

```js
function JoinedOrNot(){
    var cat = document.getElementById("category");
    if(cat.value == "Men"){
        document.getElementById("input1").disabled = false;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("input1").disabled = true;
    }
 
 if(cat.value == "Women"){
        document.getElementById("input2").disabled = false;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("input2").disabled = true;
    }
 
 if(cat.value == "Both"){
        document.getElementById("input1 input2").disabled = false;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("input1 input2").disabled = true;
    }
 
 if(cat.value == "Youth"){
        document.getElementById("input1 input2").disabled = false;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("input1 input2").disabled = true;
    }
 
 }
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("input1 input2")` will not work, you need to do it individually

Comment: Why not just use document.getElementById("input1").disabled = false and document.getElementById("input2").disabled = false ?

Comment: Why the jQuery tag? I see none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use switch instead of multiple ifs.

```js
         function JoinedOrNot() {
           var cat = document.getElementById("category").value;
           var input1Disabled = false;
           var input2Disabled = false;

           switch(cat) {
               case "Men":
                   input2Disabled = true;
               break;
               case "Women":
                   input1Disabled = true;
               break;
           }

           document.getElementById("input1").disabled = input1Disabled;
           document.getElementById("input2").disabled = input2Disabled;

         }
```

```html
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="category" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Group Category</label>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <select class="form-control" name="category" id="category" onChange="JoinedOrNot()">
              <option value="">Select Category</option>
              <option value="Men">Men</option>
              <option value="Women">Women</option>
              <option value="Youth">Youth</option>
              <option value="Both">Both</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Number Of Men</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type='text' size='5' name="man" id="input1" value="" class='input' disabled></input>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Number Of Women</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type='text' size='5' name="woman" id="input2" value="" class='input' disabled></input>
          </div>
        </div>
```